# Location of the created using gedit

Tags: windows-10, gedit

I have installed Ubuntu app on Windows 10 and also installed `gedit`. After I create a file using `gedit`, I want to access it through the File Explorer. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 1):

`gedit` is no different to any other program. So this applies to any other program you might run in WSL (if you are not talking about WSL then please edit your question).

The recommended approach is to access your Windows drives from within Linux, using the `/mnt` directory. For example, your "C:" drive is under `/mnt/c` and your Documents folder would typically be at `/mnt/c/Users/YourUserName/Documents`.

So you should save files *there* from `gedit` rather than saving them into your Ubuntu home directory.

You can create symbolic links if you want to make these locations easier to access.

Answer (score 0):

Files created on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) are located at

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\
```

This is the location of `home` directory. Now you can find your file depending on where you saved it on `gedit`. Do not attempt to modify files. If you need a file, just create a copy of the file on your machine.

Note: This method may seem most convinient, but make to to know about the consequences [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/)

Comment: This approach works but is **not recommended:** https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/